# Gitlab-ce container on portworx volume fails to open unix sockets

Tags: docker, gitlab

I’m trying to run Gitlab-ce docker container (12.6.1-ce) with a persistent volume for data (/var/opt/gitlab) configured on portworx cluster. The problem is, when Gitlab starts, it components try to open unix sockets on this volume, that is not supported.

How can I configure Gitlab to use unix sockets on another location (like /var/run), or maybe there is another solution?